# PHP: Using file_get_contents to access an API - Empty Response

Tags: php, api, file

Sorry for the messy code in advance. I want to write a code which returns me infos from the official Blizzard API, which I can then print out on my homepage. The code doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't print out something either. For Starters:

1. I would also prefer using CURL, but my homepage is on a Wordpress Hosting Site and I don't know how to install the CURL Library that way
2. allow_furl_open is on

   ```
    $url = "https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token"; 

    $data = array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials');

    //HTTP options
    $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'header'    => array ('Content-type: multipart/form-data', 'Authorization: Basic ' . 
    base64_encode("$client_id:$client_pass")),
        'content' => json_encode($data)
    )
   );

   //Do request
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    $result = json_decode($json, true);

    $accessToken = $json['access_token'];







    $tokenURL = "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/token/?namespace=dynamic-eu";
    $opts2 = array('http' =>
               array(
                   'method' => 'POST',
                   'header' => array('Content-type: multipart/form-data', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken),
                   )
               );

   $context2 = stream_context_create($opts2);
   $json2 = file_get_contents($tokenURL,false,$context2);

   $result2 = json_decode($json2, true);
   $tokenprice = $result2['price'];

   echo "<p>Tokenpreis:" .$tokenprice. "</p>";
   ```

I didn't add the $client_id and $client_pass into the code snippet, but this exists obviously. I used this [PHP CURL Snippet](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/blizzard/t/oauth2-client-credentials-implementations/131) as template. And this is a short explanation on blizzard's site on how is this supposed to work:

[image]

Anyone got any ideas what went wrong? I am really out of ideas here and would love anyone who could help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You sure about the right HTTP method?

Comment: @Sibidharan Hi thanks for the quick answer, I also thought GET makes more sense but all code snippets accessing the blizzardAPI use POST (like the link mentioned above). I also tested it out with GET though, it doesn't change anything

Comment: Yes but it didn't change anything

Comment: `Content-type: multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the curl example from the linked API docs, the content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and so for the initial request to https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token you should be able to follow the example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#refsect1-context.http-examples).

In your case this will look something like:

```
$url = 'https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token'; 

$data = array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials');

$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => array (
      'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_pass")
    ),
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Also, in your code you are storing the raw result from the initial request in `$json`, then the decoded array in `$result`, but attempting to get the `access_token` from the initial request, instead of the decoded array.